# Duplicate Management when converting leads

Tags: duplicate-management

I have created a duplicate matching rule for accounts and for contacts. When I create a new account or new contact, both matching rules will fire and highlight possible duplicates.

When I convert a lead, it seems that only possible duplicate contacts are highlighted, not accounts. For us, however, it is more important to highlight duplicate accounts when converting leads, as quite often users ignore to select an existing account, and then just create a new one during the lead conversion process.

Any help is appreciated.
Best regards, Lily.

Comment: did you try converting a lead that has a duplicate company but *not* a duplicate Contact ?  What do you observe?

Answer (score 0):

very late answer but hopefully this helps others - when converting a lead it seems that only standard fields are recognised. If your matching rule is looking at custom fields it will not highlight the potential duplicate until after conversion.

Took me ages to work out!